# Angular 2 Inheritance error

Tags: angular, inheritance

Currently I am working on a project, in which I have 2 services, UserService and SharedService.

I have one getter setter inside UserService,

```
export class UserService {
private _user: Data;

getUser(): Data {
if (!this._user) {
  this._user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(APPStorage.USER));
  this.setUser(this._user);
}
return this._user;
}

setUser(value: Data): void {
sessionStorage.setItem(APPStorage.USER, JSON.stringify(value));
this._user = value;
}
......
}
```

and

```
export class SharedService extends UserService {
....
}
```

so after updating my user, in response I call setUser method and save updated details in _user. Component looks like this,

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private sharedService: SharedService,
            private userService: UserService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
this.userDetail = this.userService.getUser();
....
}
....
}
```

Problem arise for this particular case, after updating user profile, if I logout from the system and than re-login and check my profile, It shows me before updated details. Even from backend I am getting correct updated response and if I refresh the page than I get the correct Info(means _user shows updated detail). If I change something like this inside ngOnInit my component,

```
this.userDetail = this.sharedService.getUser();
```

then there is no such problem, and It worked perfectly, I get updated info as soon as I enter in the page and no need to refresh the page. I want to know why is this happening?

Comment: What happens if you remove this check "if (!this._user)" ?

Comment: @itdoesntwork : then html code breaks down , that line is there to prevent if _user is undefined.

Comment: I still don't understand this if,,, if the storage is null and the user is undefined the html will also break, but nevermind... Check your instances.. if you have two different instances the user will be different if you call other instance on setUser and another on getUser.. also if on one instance the user never gets undefined it will never parse from session storage so you won't take the updated value.